# How can I fit a text inside of a container

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm learning the basic things, I'm using tailwind and and I'm having trouble to fit the text inside the container.

I share an Image.

Do anyone know how to let something inside of a concret height/widht and resize to occupate less space when the screen is smaller?

Thanks

[image: When the screen size gets smaller the button and text don't fit in the container]

Comment: Have you had a look at the responsive prefixes of tailwind? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design